# Reading 1 GB binary file taking too long in C

Tags: c, file-handling

I'm reading a file where the number of tuples "n_tups" and length of individual tuple or its dimension "d" are inputs. I've allocated the memory as follows,for a two dimensional array "tuple".

When I run the code my computer hangs and I don't know why.

```
if((fpp = fopen("in2.bin", "rb"))==NULL)
   printf("file in2.bin doesn't exist!");
else
{
 int **tuple;
 unsigned long i;

 tuple = malloc(n_tups * sizeof(int *));

 if(tuple == NULL)
   {
      fprintf(stderr, "out of memory\n");
      return;
   }
 for(i=0;i<n_tups;i++){
        tuple[i]=malloc(d * sizeof(int));
        if(tuple[i] == NULL)
        {
           fprintf(stderr, "out of memory\n");
           return;
         }  
  }

 fseek( fpp , 0 , SEEK_SET );
 printf("reading step");
 for(i=0;i<n_tups;i++){
         fread(&tuple[i],4,d,fpp);
         fread(&score[i],8,1,fpp);
    }

 fclose(fpp);
 }
```

I tried to check if the program ever reaches the "reading step" and it doesn't. Turns out its busy allocating the memory!
I'm passing d=3 n_tups=85013600 and my computer has 4 GBs of RAM.

Comment: What did you pass for `n_tups` and `d`?  How much RAM does your computer have?

Comment: for large n_tups and small d i would rather allocate memory once → int *tuples=malloc(n_tups*d*sizeof *tuples)

Comment: debugging hint - use `realloc` and iterate to the point it fails, or use `malloc/free` with ever increasing sizes to find where it fails.  Note that it might not be failing, it just might take that long to allocate your memory.

Comment: Or just use a database.

Comment: Why `4` and `8` instead of `sizeof(_something_)`?

Comment: @chux it has been specified as the property of this bin file by its manufacturer

Comment: @She You are missing the point made by chux: your program should have a corresponding data structure of the correct size. Then you wouldn't need the "magic numbers" 4 and 8. `int32_t` and `int64_t` comes to mind.

Comment: See also [Is malloc slow?](http://voices.canonical.com/jussi.pakkanen/2011/09/27/is-malloc-slow/). Assuming 1.5 million malloc/second, your loop would take 57 seconds. Assuming 300 000 malloc/second, your loop would take 284 seconds.

Comment: @Wimmel if malloc works so fast then the "reading step" should have been printed. I have a feeling this whole fiasco is caused by the 'sizeof(int *)' part.

Comment: @She `printf("reading step");` likely isn't printed because `stdout` is in line-buffer mode, so until `stdout` is flushed or a newline is sent to `stdout` the output will remain in the `stdout` buffer.

Comment: when there is an error, like the file could not be opened, use: `perror( "fopen for ... failed: ):  exit( EXIT_FAILURE );`  Then, 1) the reason for the failure will be displayed (along with the text in the call to perror()) so the user sees informative information.) 2) no need for a `else` statement

Comment: It would have been really nice if the posted code  `compiled` so we could help you debug the problem.

Comment: when coding/posting code: for readability/understanding, please consistently indent the code:  suggest 4 spaces for each indent level.  Never use tabs for indenting.  indent after every opening brace '{'.  un-indent before every closing brace '}'.  Separate code blocks (for, if, else, while, do...while, switch, case, default) via a blank line.

Comment: when calling `printf()` it is (usually)  best end the format parameter with `\n` so the formatted line is displayed immediately rather than when the stdout buffer gets full.  Example: `printf("reading step");` should be: `printf("reading step\n");`

Comment: when calling function: `fseek()`, always check the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: the posted code contains some 'magic' numbers.  ('magic' numbers are numbers with no basis)  I.E. 4, 8.  strongly suggest using an `enum` statement or `#define` statements to give those 'magic' numbers meaningful names, then use those meaningful names throughout the code.

Comment: Some of the variable names in the posted code are meaningless.  (example `d`).  variable names should indicate content or usage (or better both)

Comment: Please, post complete examples that allow us to compile and see results.  If you only publish a snippet of code asking for some error in your code, the most probable cause of failure for sure will go with the absent code (mainly that's the reason of your post, you don't see it, and probably your mistake is a silly one)

Answer (score 4):

There are two performance problems with the code itself.

- You are needlessly using a pointer-to-pointer lookup table even though all dimensions are the same. It would be much better to use a 2D array, so that all data is allocated in adjacent memory. That way the CPU doesn't have to go digging through the RAM for every read of the heap, but can utilize the data cache memory instead.

  Like this:

  ```
  int (*tuple)[d] = malloc( sizeof(int[n_tups][d]) );
  ...
  free(tuple);
  ```
- Each call to `fread` will be expensive. Try to read as large chunks as possible per call. What's optimal in your case, I don't know - it is system-dependent. But calling it for small chunks of data will be ineffective. Especially since a properly-written program will always check the result of every single `fread` call.

  Ideally, assuming you followed my previous advise about using a 2D array, you would only need to do:

  ```
  result = fread(tuple, sizeof(int[n_tups][d]), 1, fpp);
  ```

  However, it appears that the file contains unrelated data that you wish to store elsewhere. Consider replacing the two `int` arrays with a single array of structs instead, so that you can read longer chunks of memory each time. (However, mind struct padding.)

  Be aware that reading very large chunks of data from disk might be time-consuming, so consider doing it from a different thread and not from the main (GUI?) thread.

Comment: so if i run it in a different thread my gui won't hang ? does that need posix?

Comment: @She It depends on what system this is for. POSIX pthread are probably the best option if available. Other systems like Windows have their own non-portable thread libraries.

Comment: `fread()` shouldn't be too bad - the STDIO calls usually buffer 4k or 8k or data, which combined with normal file system page caching should allow normal `fread()` to get 90+% of maximum IO rates.  The problem is "What is that 'maximum IO rate'"?  Is the disk a large, S-L-O-W 5,400 RPM SATA drive attached by a poorly-performing commodity disk controller that's used by everything else running on the system?  Such a disk might be lucky to sustain a mere 30-40 IO operations per second.